# Annoying Biomedical Electrical Engineering Question - How do you relate circuit values to find the distance of the nodes of ranvier?

Tags: resistance, theory

Question is as follows:

[image]

I have the electrical circuit drawn as described by the question (ie, the electrical circuit representation of a membrane with Rm1 = 0, Cm1=0 then in series with Rn and a DC voltage, which is then in parallel with Cn).

But i have no idea at all how we are supposed to use this circuit to calculate the distance that the nodes of ranvier would have to be. The lecture notes give no indication or no guide as to how to do it. How do you go about solving this question??

Comment: Interesting. Perhaps you could draw a picture/schematic describing the problem, because I have no idea what that says :O

Comment: Rm is INFINITE, not 0, except at the nodes.

Comment: What i meant sorry, Rm is infinite (ie O.C). Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 1):

Rm is INFINITE, not 0, except at the nodes.

Draw the circuit from 1 node of Ranvier, where the current goes through the intracellular fluid, exits the next node, and then returns through the extracellular fluid to the original node.  This then becomes a simple voltage division question.  The longest value for which the intracellular voltage at node 2 reaches -45mV is your answer.

There will be some rise time at the nodes, because of the capacitance, but I think I would ignore it, at least as a first step.

Comment: Not entirely sure i get what you are saying. By "the longest value" are you referring to the distance. In that case, would the way to relate the voltage is that i would equate:

-45 = Vo*exp(-x/R_m*C_m) ?
(ie tau = R_n*C_n) 

Sorry - this is very confusing to me.

Comment: Okay, my "solution" (this is going to be wrong):

Voltage division:

40*(50e3/(115e3 + 50e3)) = 12.12 V 

Voltage at node 2 is 12.12V, this is Vo , whre V_cm = Vo*exp(-x) 

-45e-3 = -12.12*exp(-x) (this is wrong too)

ln(45e-3/12.12) = -x = -5.59 
Therefore x = 5.59 cm

^ Is that "sort of" the right track???